# Writing from Heroku to Amazon SQS : bad performance

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-sqs

We have a json API served from a Rails app hosted on heroku. I want to write a message on a SQS queue for an endpoint with about 800 request per minutes.
There would be one message sent per request with a very small body (100 byte strings)

Both the Queue and the Heroku app are located in Ireland.

I get an average of 150ms per write (6.6 msg/sec) this is way to slow : the average response time for that endpoint is 100ms, it's not acceptable to double the response time just by writing to SQS

Several sources states that they can write up to 50-80 msg/sec from an EC2 instance to SQS in the same region.
Heroku instances are hosted on EC2 so what could explain this difference ?
What can we do to increase the write throughput ?

Here is our setup :

- Ruby 2.1.2
- aws-sdk 1.34.1
- Heroku app located in eu region
- SQS queue located in eu-west-1
- Unicorn running on 2x dynos

Sources reporting 10x more write throughput :

http://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/scaling-with-amazon-sqs/
http://notes.variogr.am/post/67710296/replacing-amazon-sqs-with-something-faster-and-cheaper
http://www.quora.com/How-fast-is-Amazon-SQS

Comment: What are you measuring exactly? The rails overall response time or solely the time of 3d party communication? Are u measuring under load?
Post results from `Benchmark.measure { call_sqs }` from a machine which is not doing any other network communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you were measuring the total api response time of your own rails app on heroku.
To high probability it is deployed on unicorn with a couple of dyno workers. Every time web request comes in, it is handled by a unicorn worker process. As it is talking to a 3d party it will be doing blocking io communication, meaning it will cause this worker process to wait until the communication with the 3d party completes. While waiting, a unicorn worker, cannot handle any other http requests. So the bad throughput would result from your server being blocked most of the time.

You would have following options to solve this:

- Switch to a multithreaded app server (e.g. puma)
- Switch to an evented app server (e.g. thin) and perform a non blocking io http request to the 3rd party with `EventMachine.em_http_request`.

With a multithreaded solution you will have to tune your Threadpool number. Perhaps you would want to extract this feature into a separate app. Because it is totally fine to have a large Threadpool for Threads being most of the time in sleep mode, due to being blocked by io operations but not that fine for Threads doing a lot of cpu work as they will suffer from context switching.

Being evented is a bit tricky with Rails and thin if you want also deliver the response to the client on the 3rd party call finished. But it seems [possible](http://www.jonb.org/2013/01/25/async-rails.html). It's a nobrainer with [async_sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra). One could also use some publish subscribe solution for the async responses.